# No maintenance, maintenance (admin) and console

Tags: console, maintenance

In response to the previous question I'd like to share my error with the maintenance options of MiKteX. Whenever I try to start the package manager, settings or update menu I get a message saying the shortcut is missing. Furthermore, there is NO MikTeX Console installed.

What can I do to regain access to these programs? I added a printscreen of my startmenu as well.

[image: MikTeX Start Menu]

Comment: The programms are gone. Delete the links, they do nothing. Then search the miktex console, normally it should be in the same folder as miktex-pdftex.

Comment: Yes, I found MikTex console. On my laptop it is the following file path: D:\Applications\Protext\Program\miktex\bin\x64. Within this folder you have to search for "miktex-console". Thank you for your answer!